# No Input File Specified - Joomla

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

I have recently moved a website from one host to another, it's a joomla installation and I got everything to work in the end, however when trying to download the 7 day trial, it says "No Input file specified", I have no idea how this is related to just that file, I have searched endless on this issue and most people have issued with their htaccess it seems.

https://www.arbershop-pro.com/ (try to download the 7 day trial)

this is my htaccess:

```
 ##
 # @version $Id: htaccess.txt 21064 2011-04-03 22:12:19Z dextercowley $
 # @package Joomla
 # @copyright Copyright (C) 2005 - 2010 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
 # @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU/GPL
 # Joomla! is Free Software
 ##

 #####################################################
 #  READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE
 #
 # The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
 # with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
 # be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
 # your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
 # beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
 # it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
 #
 #####################################################

 ##  Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
 Options +FollowSymLinks

 #
 #  mod_rewrite in use

 RewriteEngine On

 ########## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits
 ## If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
 ## This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
 #
 ## Deny access to extension xml files (uncomment out to activate)
 #<Files ~ "\.xml$">
 #Order allow,deny
 #Deny from all
 #Satisfy all
 #</Files>
 ## End of deny access to extension xml files
 # Block out any script trying to set a mosConfig value through the URL
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
 # Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
 # Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
 # Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
 # Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
 # Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
 RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
 #
 ########## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits

 ########## Begin - Custom redirects
 #
 # If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
 # www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
 # redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
 #
 ########## End - Custom redirects

 #  Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
 #  is not directly related to physical file paths.
 #  Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root)

  RewriteBase /

 ########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section
 #
 RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
 #
 # If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
 # has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
 # and the request is for root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
 # requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|raw))$ [NC]
 # and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 # and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 # internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
 RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
 #
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

 ########## End - Joomla! core SEF Section

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://arbershop-pro.com/.*$      [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://arbershop-pro.com$      [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.arbershop-pro.com/.*$      [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.arbershop-pro.com$      [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.arbershop-pro.com/.*$      [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.arbershop-pro.com$      [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://arbershop-pro.com/.*$      [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://arbershop-pro.com$      [NC]
 RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$ - [F,NC]
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a JavaScript issue:

```js
function populateIframe(name,email,id,path) 
{
    var ifrm = document.getElementById(id);
    ifrm.src = "https://www.arbershop-pro.com/\modules\mod_trial_download/jsQuery.php?path="+path+"&name="+name+"&email="+email;
                                    problem --^-------^
}
```

Fix the URL as

```
https://www.arbershop-pro.com/modules/mod_trial_download/jsQuery.php?path=
```

and the download starts working.

---

Okay, shifting gears to PHP now :) Output the `jsQueryPath` as

```php
<?php echo str_replace('\\', '/', $jsQueryPath); ?>
```

Comment: function populateIframe(name,email,id,path) 
    {
        var ifrm = document.getElementById(id);
        ifrm.src = "<?php echo $jsQueryPath;?>?path="+path+"&name="+name+"&email="+email;
    }

This is the function, it is grabbed from from a variable. I have setup a development server as I have real troubles with that server which it is loaded on.

See: https://37.26.108.168/~arbersho

It is working here, without any adjustments however none of the images work, 403 forbidden (all directories are 755, files 644 and owner is correct) is this because of the temporary URL?

Comment: More detailed set up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499651/no-input-file-specified-joomla

Comment: I've updated the `$jsQueryPath` fix above. The images 403 Forbidden issue is out of scope. Please open a new question with your environment details.

Comment: Thanks Ravi, I have actually fixed the 403 forbidden issue and all is working correctly on the development server, I am suspecting is an issue with the permissions and the Windows server which the not so great host provides. If all goes bad and the client needs to stay with this server I will attempt to use your fix, but I have noticed there are other issues there too

Comment: Glad you got that sorted.