# Joomla Temporary URL images forbidden 403

Tags: image, joomla, http-status-code-403

I have setup a development server for an issue(see [No Input File Specified - Joomla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499651/no-input-file-specified-joomla)), all is working correct now on the development server apart from no images on the site or inside the administration menu are loading.

When I try to look at them individually they are 403 forbidden.

```
http://37.26.108.168/~arbersho/
```

All directories are 755, all files are 644 and the owner is the correct one.

Is this because of the temporary URL and will this be fixed by pointing the domain over?

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This was a htaccess issue which is fixed.